# $2\left[(mz)^2 + (px)^2 + pmy^2\right] + \left[(nz)^2 + (nx)^2 + (py)^2 + (my)^2\right] \ge 2(2pmzx + pnzy + mnxy + pnxy + mnzy)$

Tags: inequality

> $x, y, z$ and $m, n, p$ are reals. Prove/disprove that $$2\large \left[(mz)^2 + (px)^2 + pmy^2\right] + \left[(nz)^2 + (nx)^2 + (py)^2 + (my)^2\right] \ge 2(2pmzx + pnzy + mnxy + pnxy + mnzy)$$

That's the problem and I don't know how to do it.

My original idea is to convert the difference between the left and right side into a sum of squares then using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (Bunyakovsky not being credited) but it came to no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is false because with (x,y,z,m,n,p)=(1,1,1,1,1,1) you get $10\ge 12$

The inequality $\ 2pmy^2\ge pnzy + mnxy + pnxy + mnzy\ $ is also false because with (x,y,z,m,n,p)=(1,1,1,1,1,1) you get $2\ge 4$ but if you assume it is true you can still derive the original inequality.

(a) $\ \frac{(nz)^2 +(py)^2}{2}\ge pnzy\ $

(b) $\ \frac{(nx)^2 +(my)^2}{2}\ge mnxy\ $

(c) $\ \frac{(nx)^2 +(py)^2}{2}\ge pnxy\ $

(d) $\ \frac{(nz)^2 +(my)^2}{2}\ge mnzy\ $

(e) $\ 2[(mz)^2 + (px)^2]\ge 4pmzx\ $

(f) $\ 2pmy^2\ge pnzy + mnxy + pnxy + mnzy\quad $(this is false)

a+b+c+d$\Rightarrow$

(g) $\ [(nz)^2 + (nx)^2 + (py)^2 + (my)^2]\ge pnzy + mnxy + pnxy + mnzy\ $

e+g $\ \Rightarrow$

h) $\ 2[(mz)^2 + (px)^2] + [(nz)^2 + (nx)^2 + (py)^2 + (my)^2] \ge 4pmzx + pnzy + mnxy + pnxy + mnzy$

f+h $\ \Rightarrow$

$\ 2[(mz)^2 + (px)^2 + pmy^2] + [(nz)^2 + (nx)^2 + (py)^2 + (my)^2] \ge 2(2pmzx + pnzy + mnxy + pnxy + mnzy)$